# Rails has_many :through and Setting Property on Join model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, join

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408872/rails-has-many-through-find-by-extra-attributes-in-join-model), how do I set a property on the join model just before save in this context?

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_assets
  has_many :assets, :through => :post_assets
  has_many :featured_images, :through => :post_assets, :class_name => "Asset", :source => :asset, :conditions => ['post_assets.context = ?', "featured"]

end

class PostAssets < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :asset

  # context is so we know the scope or role
  # the join plays
  validates_presences_of :context
end

class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_assets
  has_many :posts, :through => :post_assets
end
```

I just want to be able to do this:

```
@post = Post.create!(:title => "A Post")
@post.featured_images << Asset.create!(:title => "An Asset")
# ...
@post = Post.first
@featured = @post.featured_images.first
  #=> #<Asset id: 1, title: "An Asset">
@featured.current_post_asset #=> #<PostAsset id: 1, context: "featured">
```

How would that work?  I've been banging my head over it all day :).

What currently happens is when I do this:

```
@post.featured_images << Asset.create!(:title => "An Asset")
```

Then the join model `PostAsset` that gets created never gets a chance to set `context`.  How do I set that context property?  It looks like this:

```
PostAsset.first #=> #<PostAsset id: 1, context: nil>
```

**Update**:

I have created a test [gem](http://github.com/viatropos/acts-as-joinable) to try to isolate the problem.  Is there an easier way to do this?!

This [ActsAsJoinable::Core class](http://github.com/viatropos/acts-as-joinable/blob/master/lib/acts_as_joinable/core.rb) makes it so you can have many to many relationships with a context between them in the join model.  And it adds helper methods.  The basic [tests](http://github.com/viatropos/acts-as-joinable/blob/master/test/test_acts_as_joinable.rb) show basically what I'm trying to do.  Any better ideas on how to do this properly?

Comment: This also seems similar to my question earlier this week:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035064/updating-extra-attributes-in-a-has-many-through-relationship-using-rails

I just retroactively change the join model. I assume there must be a callback, however, to do work on the join model before it is saved. +1 'cause I'm curious.

Comment: there is a `before_add` and `after_add` callback on the non-join model (so `assets` on the Post), but you can't really access the join model any way without calling `PostAsset.first(:conditions => {...})`.  It seems like it's a missing feature in Rails after reading all the forums.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the has_many options in the ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods API located here: http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001316

This is the most interesting quote:

> **:conditions**
>
> Specify the conditions that the associated object must meet in order to be included as a WHERE SQL fragment, such as authorized = 1. Record creations from the association are scoped if a hash is used. has_many :posts, :conditions => {:published => true} will create published posts with @blog.posts.create or @blog.posts.build.

So I believe your conditions must be specified as a hash, like so:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_assets
  has_many :featured_post_assets, :conditions => { :context => 'featured' }

  has_many :assets, :through => :post_assets

  has_many :featured_images, :through => :featured_post_assets,
           :class_name => "Asset", :source => :asset,
end
```

And you should also do the following:

```
@post.featured_images.build(:title => "An asset")
```

instead of:

```
@post.featured_images << Asset.create!(:title => "An Asset")
```

This should call the scoped asset build, as suggested in the quote above to add the context field to asset.  It will also save both the join model object (post_asset) and the asset object to the database at the same time in one atomic transaction.

Comment: what about `@post.featured_images << Asset.first` and related (not actually building/creating it)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure build doesn't save the new record until the @post object is saved.  << will save the new object before the @post object is saved, create will do the same.

Comment: This does not work with :through associations. At least not in Rails 3.2.12. When specifying conditions on a through association, object.association.build does not set those conditions. Maybe this is a bug in Rails, or just not meant to work with :through associations.

Comment: If anyone else runs into this, the right way to set the conditions is on the join model. So, in the above example it would turn into something like has_many :featured_post_assets, :conditions => { :context => "featured" }. Then leave off the conditions from :featured_images association.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the changes suggested by @davekaro

Comment: In Rails4 using `:conditions` is now deprecated in favor of a lambda. I've asked a very similar question to this one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098708/losing-an-attribute-when-saving-through-an-association-w-scope-rails-4-0-0-rc2