# Rails - joiner model with a flag, condition not saving?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Here are my models:

Team:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :team_users

  has_many :users, through: :team_users

  has_many :admins, through: :team_users,
                    foreign_key: :user_id,
                    class_name: 'User',
                    source: :user,
                    conditions: ["team_users.is_admin = ?", true]
end
```

User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :team_users

  has_many :teams, through: :team_users

  has_many :administered_teams, through: :team_users,
                                foreign_key: :user_id,
                                class_name: 'Team',
                                source: :team,
                                conditions: ["team_users.is_admin = ?", true]


end
```

TeamUser:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: team_users
#
#  id       :integer          not null, primary key
#  team_id  :integer
#  user_id  :integer
#  is_admin :boolean
#

class TeamUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :user

  # Validations
  validates_presence_of :team
  validates_presence_of :user

  attr_accessible :is_admin

end
```

So essentially `team.users` and `team.admins` are joined through the same table. Note that to be a `team.admin` you must be a `team.user`.

My question is, how do I save `is_admin` in the joiner-model automatically when I append to `team.admins`? i.e:

```
irb(main):001:0> user = User.find(1)
irb(main):002:0> team = Team.create
irb(main):003:0> team.admins << user
irb(main):004:0> team.users.count
              => 1
irb(main):005:0> team.admins.count
              => 0

irb(main):007:0> y team.team_users
               - !ruby/object:TeamUser
                 attributes:
                   id: 307
                   team_id: 210
                   user_id: 1
                   is_admin: 
                     => nil
```

I remember vaguely seeing somewhere that has_many conditions are automatically set. But I'm not sure if this is the case for joiner models? Or perhaps I'm doing it wrong and there is a better implementation?

### Update

This question seems very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081764/rails-has-many-through-and-setting-property-on-join-model).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Based on the suggestion given in the [question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081764/rails-has-many-through-and-setting-property-on-join-model) in your [comment to another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16046685/rails-joiner-model-with-a-flag-condition-not-saving/16046970#comment-22936571), you can fix this if you assign the conditions hash to the join model instead of the has_many_through association:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  # standard join model
  has_many :team_users

  # join model with conditions
  has_many :team_admins, class_name: 'TeamUser', conditions: {is_admin: true}

  # uses standard join association
  has_many :users, through: team_users

  # uses the conditional join association
  has_many :admins, through: team_admins, source: user
end

team.admins << user
team.admins.count
=> 1
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Don't append through the `admins` has-many-through association. Rather append like this:

```
team.team_users << TeamUser.new(user: user, is_admin: true)
```

Or you can just use the magic `create_` helper method:

```
team.create_team_users(user: user, is_admin: true)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to use this as a workaround. But it would still be nice to have a cleaner solution...

Comment: @NathanKot: Updated based on the answer given in the other question you linked to.  Essentially, the conditions won't work as you like if you put them on the has-many-through association.  But it will work if you put them on a new join model association and use that for your has-many-through association.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the conditions option from a SQL fragment to a hash.

From Rails' API documentation:

> Record creations from the association are scoped if a hash is used.
>   `has_many :posts, :conditions => {:published => true}` will create
>   published posts with `@blog.posts.create` or `@blog.posts.build`.

In your case, it would become:

```
has_many :administered_teams, through: :team_users,
                              foreign_key: :user_id,
                              class_name: 'Team',
                              source: :team,
                              conditions: { team_users: { is_admin: true }}
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing up that a hash is required in the condition, however in this case it doesn't seem to work... Seems related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081764/rails-has-many-through-and-setting-property-on-join-model) (which hasn't been answered)