# Losing an Attribute When Saving Through an Association w/ Scope (Rails 4.0.0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, ruby-on-rails-4

### The Code (Rails 4.0.0)

```
class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :artist_tracks
  has_many :owning_artists,
              -> { where(:artist_tracks => { :artistic_role_id => 1 }) },
              :through => :artist_tracks,
              :source => :artist
end

class ArtistTrack < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artist
  belongs_to :track
  belongs_to :artistic_role
end

class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :artist_tracks
  has_many :tracks, :through => :artist_tracks
end
```

### Finding Works

```
# artist_tracks.artistic_role_id is properly set to "1"
2.0.0p195 :003 > Track.last.owning_artists

  Track Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "tracks".* FROM "tracks" ORDER BY "tracks"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  Artist Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "artists".* FROM "artists" INNER JOIN "artist_tracks" ON "artists"."id" = "artist_tracks"."artist_id" WHERE "artist_tracks"."artistic_role_id" = 1 AND "artist_tracks"."track_id" = $1  [["track_id", 10]]
```

### Create Does Not Work

```
# artist_tracks.artistic_role_id is totally missing from the INSERT

2.0.0p195 :005 > Track.create!(name: "test_name", lyrics: "test_lyrics", owning_artist_ids: [1])

  Artist Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "artists".* FROM "artists" WHERE "artists"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.5ms)  BEGIN
  Artist Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "artists" WHERE ("artists"."name" = 'TestArtist1' AND "artists"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "tracks" ("created_at", "lyrics", "name", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Thu, 13 Jun 2013 22:20:14 UTC +00:00], ["lyrics", "test_lyrics"], ["name", "test_name"], ["updated_at", Thu, 13 Jun 2013 22:20:14 UTC +00:00]]
#
# Y U NO have artist_tracks.artistic_role_id?
#
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "artist_tracks" ("artist_id", "created_at", "track_id", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["artist_id", 1], ["created_at", Thu, 13 Jun 2013 22:20:14 UTC +00:00], ["track_id", 12], ["updated_at", Thu, 13 Jun 2013 22:20:14 UTC +00:00]]
   (1.0ms)  COMMIT
```

According to the [Rails Guide for Active Record Associations (4.3.3.1 where)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#scopes-for-has-many-where), I believe my usage of the scope and expectation are valid:

> If you use a hash-style where option, then record creation via this
>   association will be automatically scoped using the hash.

Why is the `artist_tracks.artistic_role_id` attribute being lost?  If my expectations are wrong, I'd like to understand why and how to implement an alternative solution.

I have also listed this as [an issue on the Rails repo](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10945).  Any insight is appreciated! Thank you

Comment: do i understand you correctly: you assume, that `artistic_role_id` should be set like within your association scope when you create that association?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: in rails3 this should work with the `:conditions` attribute. i can't find any documentation on this in rails4 https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb#L175

Comment: In rails 4 :conditions has been deprecated in preference of using a lambda and rails will bitch about it w/ deprecation warnings.

Comment: i would try asking this on the guides mailing list https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/rubyonrails-docs

Comment: @phoet thanks. I was also told by a rails contributor in #RubyOnRails to submit a bug on the rails github repo. I'll give it a shot and report back.

Comment: I'm having this issue as well. Any resolution?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what is happening is that the associated model actually being created here is the join model, `artist_tracks`, and not the association with the actual conditions on it.  You could probably fix this by declaring an alternate join association with conditions on it, and then attaching `owning_artists` through that instead.  Like this:

```
class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :artist_tracks
  has_many :owning_artist_tracks,
              -> { where(:artistic_role_id => 1) },
              :class_name => "ArtistTrack"
  has_many :owning_artists,
              :through => :owning_artist_tracks,
              :source => :artist
end
```

Comment: I actually tried this exact code before posting my question and unfortunately the conditional (owning_artist_tracks.artistic_role_id) is still totally missing from the `INSERT` statement.  Interestingly, in Rails 3 your method works (assuming you use `:conditions` instead of the lambda (`:conditions` is deprecated in rails4)).

Comment: Ah, I see.  I'll admit that I do not have Rails 4 experience, so that suggestion was indeed based on Rails 3.