# Rails: has many :through assignment with 3rd foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following code which when run creates / deletes records on table project_users using a has many through relationship and this works fine.

```
@project.users = @account.users.find(params[:users_ids])
```

However, i'm now in a situation where I need to set a 3rd foreign key value on this middle project_users table called role_id.

Are there any suggestions to efficiently set the role_id at the same time as the code above.

I've come up with a couple of solutions such as the one below, but I don't like the idea of deleting all records if only an update is required.

```
  users = @account.users.find(params[:users_granted].keys)
  @project.users = []
  users.each do |user|
    @project.project_users.create(:user_id => user.id, :project_role_id => params[:users_granted][user.id.to_s])
  end
```

Any thoughts / suggestions would be welcome, chances are i'm thinking about this the completely wrong way!

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: Could this be what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035064/updating-extra-attributes-in-a-has-many-through-relationship-using-rails